# Can you use dot notation with ViewData in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, dictionary, razor-pages

I'm using Razor Pages and trying to access a property from `ViewData`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Property"] = "Value";
}
```

I know this works:

```
<h1>@ViewData["Property"]
```

However, the app crashes when I try to access it with dot notation:

```
<h1>@ViewData.Property</h1>
```

Why does this hapen?

I know dot notation works with `ViewBag` since it allows me to access properties dynamically.

Comment: Why can you do `ViewData["Property"]` but you cannot do `int age = 20; if (age.IsLegal) {...}`. Same reason: The type doesn't support it because they are different things.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewData` is object of type `ViewDataDictionary` which is actually `IDictionary<string,object>` while `ViewBag` is `dynamic`. `dynamic` allows to use dot notation while dictionary in C# allows to get values only via `[key]`, so your app crashes because there is no such property `Property` in `ViewDataDictionary` even if there is such key.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewData is IDictionary which means you can access data using key (ViewData[yourkey]). But your concern is also valid, we want to access property so we can reduce risk of some teammates mis type the key.

And for that reason, I always prefer to use @Model.YourProperty. Then next question, if you got a common used field for all pages such as Languague, LoginName, ... Then I suggest to have a base Model to contain all those properties. And all page model needs to inherit/implement those properties.